# Type of member 'By' is not IWebElement or IList<IWebElement>

Tags: c#, selenium

I have made a number of tests using Selenium with a Page Object Model pattern. I'm trying to pass a `By` so I can access an element by its name. However in my `PageFactory.InitElements(excelSession,  ribbon);` method I get an exception of `Type of member 'By' is not IWebElement or IList<IWebElement>`. Is there a way to get this method to accept `By`?

My code is as follows

```
public class ExcelRibbon
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Create")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public By Create { get; set; }
}
```

Where I receive my error

```
public static ExcelRibbon ribbon = new ExcelRibbon();
PageFactory.InitElements(excelSession,  ribbon);
webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(ribbon.Create));
webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(excelSession.FindElement(ribbon.Create))).Click();
```

StackTrace

> at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.DefaultPageObjectMemberDecorator.CreateProxyObject(Type
>   memberType, IElementLocator locator, IEnumerable`1 bys, Boolean
>   cache)

Comment: Add the error trace in question

Comment: @ShubhamJain I have added a stackTrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a `FindsBy` attribute, it's expecting to use the locator method described there to locate an element. `By` is a locator, not an element (as stated in the error). I don't know what you mean by

> Is there a way to get this method to accept `By`?

You aren't declaring a method, you are declaring a field as type `By`. Either change the type from `By` to `IWebElement`

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Create")]
[CacheLookup]
public IWebElement Create { get; set; }
```

or remove the decorators and declare a locator

```
public By Create = By.Name("Create");
```

or create a method, maybe something like

```
public void Create(By locator)
{
    // do something
}
```